# Socrata Catalog Search API (beta) - result order?

Tags: api, search, socrata

How are results being sorted in the Socrata Catalog Search API (beta)?
Is there or will there be a way to control this (e.g. relevance/scoring)?

Currently adding parameters to the search URL currently affect the sort order. For example:
http://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?&domains=data.cityofnewyork.us
and
http://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?&domains=data.cityofnewyork.us&limit=20
return resources in different order. Likewise if adding &offset=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results are currently supported by relevance, and there's no external way to tweak the ordering of results.

I'm seeing the same thing as you when modifying the {{offset}}. I'll let our engineering team know and see what they say.

Comment: Aha! Already heard back from our engineering team, and with no search term, results are returned in an arbitrary order. If you enter a search term, the results are returned in a consistent order (relevance) across {{offset}}s. http://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?domains=data.cityofnewyork.us&offset=5&q=Crime